# Встречено 'else', а ожидался оператор(52 строчка)

Tags: pascalabc.net

```
program gfg;
const n = 10;

type
  mas = array[1..n] of integer;
  var a:mas;
procedure vib(var z:mas);
var 
  max, id_max, i, j,c,o,p: integer;
begin
o:= 0;
p:= 1;
writeln('изначальный');
  for i := 1 to n do begin
      z[i] := random(2000) - 999;
      write(z[i], ' ')
  end;
  
  writeln;

  j := n;

  while j > 1 do begin
      max := z[1];
      id_max := 1;
      for i := 2 to j do
          if z[i] > max then begin
              max := z[i];
              id_max := i
          end;
      z[id_max] := z[j];
      z[j] := max;
      j := j - 1
  end;
  writeln;
writeln( 'отсортированный');
  for i := 1 to n do 
    begin
    
      write(z[i], ' ');
      end;
      
for c := 1 to n-1 do
begin
p:= p + 1;
  o:= o + 1;
  if a[c] < a[c + 1] then
    begin
    writeln;
    writeln(o, ' элемент в упорядоченном массиве меньше ', p,  ' элемента');
    end;     
  else
    writeln('Порядок возрастания нарушен. ', o, ' элемент больше ', p,' элемента')
end;
end;
begin
vib(a)
end.
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что здесь не за забором.

Answer (score -1):

В 50-ой строке лишняя точка с запятой? Или в 51-ой - точно лишняя.

Comment: Я убирал уже.Не помогает

Comment: В 51-ой лишняя. Есть аналогичные вопросы.